# Check if a file exists with puppet template

Tags: ruby, puppet

I try to check if a file exists on client who run puppet agent.
On my puppet master, I have a template.erb like this :

```
<% if File.exists?('/usr/bin/lwp-request') %>SCRIPTWHITELIST="/usr/bin/lwp-request"<% end %>
```

This little code in my template is needed to my rkhunter module.
The result is always false, however the file exists.

If I add the file on the puppet master, the result is true. So the ruby code seems to be executed on the master.

How can I check on my template if a file exists on client ?

Tested on puppet 2.7.5 and 2.8.1.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? To have something included into results from the template only if file exists (or does not exist) ie. a conditional part in a template?

Answer (score 1):

The only information you have about the node when compiling manifests and templates are [Facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html) that are sent by the node when requesting a catalog.

If you need additional information from the node, then you need to add a [Custom Fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html) that retrieves the information you need (like whether or not a file exists). You can then use the custom fact inside of templates.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Puppet module create a custom fact `lib/facter/lwp.rb`:

```
Facter.add(:lwp_request_exists) do
  setcode do
    File.exists?('/usr/bin/lwp-request')
  end
end
```

then within erb template use something like:

```
<% if $::lwp_request_exists -%>
some code...
<% end -%>
```